# Как можно скачать шрифты с сайта?

Tags: css

Есть сайт, к которому прикреплён CSS-файл, в котором прописаны шрифты. CSS-файл [ЗДЕСЬ](http://homeprofitmasters.com/IFHnc/styles/style3.css).
Как можно скачать шрифты, используемые на этом сайте. Ввожу URL шрифта, выдаёт ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ttf](http://homeprofitmasters.com/IFHnc/styles/Lato-Light-webfont.ttf) вполне себе качается. остальные может просто не доделали...